# HttpClient vs HtmlUnit

Tags: java, httpclient, htmlunit

I know that `HtmlUnit` simulates a browser, while `HttpClient` doesn't.

In `HtmlUnit`, when a page is loaded and there is a JavaScript inside, will the script be executed? If the script sets a cookie, will the cookie set in `HtmlUnit`'s browser and accessible from Java code?

Is there anything that can be done using `HttpClient`, but not using `HtmlUnit`? In `HtmlUnit`, can we start with a POST request and modify any part of HTTP request including method, URI, HTTP version, headers, and body?

What are the advantages of `HttpClient` over `HtmlUnit`?

Answer (score 5):

`HttpClient` is a library at a lower-level, to send HTTP requests and retrieve responses.

`HtmlUnit` is at a higher level, and internally uses `HttpClient` to make HTTP requests, but also handles JavaScript (through `Rhino` and internal DOM implementation), XPath (through `Xalan`), CSS (through `CSSParser`), malformed HTML (through `NekoHtml`), WebSockets (through `Jetty`), etc.

You can modify the outgoing requests and response in `HtmlUnit` by something like:

```
new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) {

    public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
        WebResponse response = super.getResponse(request);
        if (request.getUrl().toExternalForm().contains("my_url")) {
            String content = response.getContentAsString("UTF-8");

            //change content

            WebResponseData data = new WebResponseData(content.getBytes("UTF-8"),
                    response.getStatusCode(), response.getStatusMessage(), response.getResponseHeaders());
            response = new WebResponse(data, request, response.getLoadTime());
        }
        return response;
    }
};
```

as hinted [here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse).

You can change the used `HttpClient` in `HtmlUnit` by overriding `HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient()`.

You can make `POST` request by:

```
WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.POST);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);
```